# Static call from Remix

Tags: remix

I have a state-changing function (not `view` and not `pure`) in a contract and I'd like to call it with a static call in Remix so I can inspect the return values. It seems like a reasonable thing to do but I'm stuck on figuring out how with the Remix UI.

Is that supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can currently inspect return values from static calls via Remix UI. I've searched the doc in PDF for `static call` but couldn't find any related information.

See: https://readthedocs.org/projects/remix-ide/downloads/pdf/latest/

Comment: Thanks for looking. I couldn't find it either.